# How to get the data from 2 different collections using lookup and how to add some condition in lookup to get the data based on some condition?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections as shown below:

First collection:

```json
[{
    "UID" : 3398,
    "name" : "test"
}]
```

Second collection:

```json
[{
    "ques_id" : "q1",
    "ri_score" : 5.3,
    "uc_id" : 3398
},
{
    "ques_id" : "q2",
    "ri_score" : 5.3,
    "uc_id" : 3398
}]
```

The query which I am using is given below:

```js
db.first_collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "second_collection",
      localField: "UID",
      foreignField: "uc_id",
      as: "second_collection_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "UID": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "second_collection_docs.ri_score": 1
    }
  }
])
```

The above query returns the data as shown below:

```json
{
    "UID" : 3394,
    "name" : "test",
    "second_collection_docs" : [{
            "ri_score" : "5.3"
        }, 
        {
            "ri_score" : "5.3"
        }]
}
```

In the second collection data it is giving the same ri_score 2 times but I want it only one time. The expected result is shown below:

```json
{
    "UID" : 3394,
    "name" : "test",
    "second_collection_docs" : [{
            "ri_score" : "5.3"
        }]
}
```

Is there any solution for this so that I can get the expected result? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could work using `$addFields` and `$reduce`:

```js
db.first_collection.aggregate([
  {}, //lookup stage
  {}, // project stage
  //Above the same query you have and here insert this stage
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "values": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$values",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this.ri_score",
                  "$$value.ri_score"
                ]
              },
              "$$value",
              {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Basically this query add the field `values` which is an array with objects that `ri_score` is not repeated.

Check this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9hCdkKmmW0E) where I've added another object with different `ri_score` and check if it works as you expected.

Also an example with your values is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h2uYToWu8a5). As you can see, `ri_score` is not duplicated.